# Como carregar conteúdo de outros arquivos usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho um campo:

```
<div class="conteudo"></div>
```

.

Estou querendo colocar o sequinte texto dentro do div conteúdo

```
<p>Conteúdo</p>
```

.

Para tentar atingir este objetivo estou usando o seguinte script:

```
var output=document.querySelector("div.conteudo");
var input=new XMLHttpRequest();
input.open("GET","conteudo.html")
input.addEventListener("load",function(){
  output.innerHTML=input.responseText;
})
input.send();
```

.

Porem estou recebendo o seguinte error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/test/conteudo.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

.

Como eu faço para carregar objetos html dinamicamente usando javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra testes locais não é possível executar uma chamada a um arquivo pois o navegador bloqueia pois não identifica a origem da chamada, o CORS, principalmente no Chrome.

A sugestão é utilizar um micro servidor, tipo npm serve ou python -S pra poder chamar esses arquivos por URL dentro do seu JS.